# Are there any Dragons myths about dragons being the creators of creation? Supernatural beings -as it were - that created the landscape?

Tags: mythical-creatures, origins, creation, dragons

I don't have a link to share, just seems to me that ancient man read the landscape and its spiritual and supernatural significance seems to pivot mostly around Dragon myths.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you talking about geomancy?  Could you please clarify.

Comment: I am far from an expert in the field, but a colleague of mine has been studying this area and come to the conclusion that the commonality of Dragon myths amongst the great civilisations, were all based on mans relationship to the landscape. As I have looked into this further I came across a fair amount about Geomancy but have no direct connection.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for, a dragon that created the whole universe, a dragon that created the earth, a dragon that created a specific landscape or one that destroyed everything and that became later the world we know today?
I think all of them would answer your question so it makes your question too broad.
I would also suggest you to show your actual research, any link that you found yourself on that subject

Comment: I’m most grateful to you for your response. . I’m looking for all source material where Dragons created this world and landscaped the mountains and valleys - a commonality of dragons being the elemental originators of creation. The Chinese have Yinglong, the dragon that literally created the Yellow river, with her tail (and the help of the Kings men) The life giving force from which sprung all the benefits of controlled agriculture, even the birth of the canals. One could even go so far as to say that taming of the Yellow River was the birth of civilisation..

Comment: The Red Dragon of Wales I’ve understood is synonymous to the Gower pinnacular, (known as ‘worms head’) here it as if the Dragon literally is the landscape -peel back the skin, the soil is oxidised red by years of volcanic activity, could well explain why the Welsh Dragon is Red. the most important myth in the Rig Veda, the myth of Indra, narrates the battle against Vitra, the gigantic dragon who held back the waters, which when released created the oceans  and the birth of creation. I don’t have any links that I could actually share I wish I did…is that good start Much appreciated M

Answer (score 3):

**Tiamat:**

[Tiamat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiamat#:%7E:text=In%20the%20religion%20of%20ancient,the%20chaos%20of%20primordial%20creation.) is a Mesopotamian creator goddess who, along with her mate [Apsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abzu) represent the waters and together give birth to the gods. After the gods murder Apsu to gain power, Tiamat (portrayed as a sea dragon) gives birth to the first dragons and makes war on the gods in revenge. When she is killed by [Marduk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marduk) (sometimes also described as a dragon or being served by dragons), the heaven and Earth are made from Tiamat's body.

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 2):

**Academic Books on 'Dragonology':**

Chinese Emperors and Sages are said to be sons of Heaven, therefore celestial dragons- **Zhao, Qiguang. 2013. Dragons, East and West.**

Humanity as Dragon-offspring of Igigi Aw-Ila and Dragon Annuna as Creator-Gods: **Foster, Benjamin R. 2005. Before the muses: an anthology of Akkadian literature. Bethesda, Md: CDL Press.**

Graeco-Roman dragon cults, suppressed by Christianity: **Ogden, Daniel. 2013. Drakōn: dragon myth and serpent cult in the Greek and Roman worlds. Oxford, U.K.: Oxford University Press.**

The evolution of the dragon in the West (update, there is a new fascinating book): **Daniel Ogden. 2021. The Dragon in the West: From Ancient Myth to Modern Legend.**

There is an interesting article here: **Jaakko Aronen: Dragon Cults and Nymphe Drakaina in IGUR 974  aus: Zeitschrift für Papyrologie und Epigraphik 111 (1996) 125–132** Link below:

http://www.uni-koeln.de/phil-fak/ifa/zpe/downloads/1996/111pdf/111125.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by dragons, if you are thinking of the typical Tolkien giant lizard, fire breathing, winged fantasy animal it is going to be hard to find very early myths containing those, as these dragons are relatively modern (13th century).

If you instead allow for large mythological serpents with fantastical features then there are many myths.

In Mesopotamian mythology, Tiamat, as presented in the *Enûma Elish* is a large monstrous sea serpent that shaped the world (with the help of another god) and created the gods and monsters. Similarly, Gucumatz/Kukulkan/Quetzalcoatl in Mesoamerican mythology, is a feathered serpent that also brought forth the earth (with the help of another god) from the waters of creation. Australian Rainbow Snake is also a creator god. There is also the Greek Orphic alternative myths where a cosmic egg gives origin to the cosmos, usually hatched by a serpent.

Other honorable mentions of mythological snakes related to early myths of first gods include Egyptian Apophis (born from Ra), Greek Typhon (father of monsters) and Chinese Nüwa (creator of mankind).